# HTML FLEXBOX(Make a evenly perfect square)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to make the box size to be evenly as perfect square and make the words inside of it to shrink. I want to make it square and the inside word to shrink to small size based on the square, but they just flexing because of the contents.

[image: this is output]

This is my code, what should I change/remove/add?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mainbox {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
}

.mainbox div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#column {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>FlexSpiral</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mainbox">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>
      box 2
      <div id="row">
        <div id="column">
          <div id="row">
            <div>box 5</div>
            <div>
              <div>box 6</div>
              <div id="row">
                <div>
                  <div id="row">
                    <div>box 9</div>
                    <div>box 10</div>
                  </div>
                  <div>box 8</div>
                </div>
                <div>box 7</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>box 4</div>
        </div>
        <div>box 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ids are unique, use class instead

Comment: Hi 123... welcome to SO! First do what @Cédric said, and: where do you specify the boxes to be *square* (aspect ratio 1:1) in the code? Flexbox just stretches, wraps and moves child elements given available space, no auto text scaling. At the moment your elements are only square by accident. Also, resizing text to fit inside an element requires linear math and probably javascript. Are you up for that?

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I don't know javascript yet. I'm just practicing css, I thought the "flex: 1" makes the 2 square even, but it's not. The box 2 keep resizing and taking the size of the box 1 which is not making the "flex:1" work. But thank you for your answer tho.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the question, but here goes

You can take the margin from the ".mainbox" that it is giving margin on all sides of the mainbox class.
To leave the div box occupying its own content you can use in the styling: `display:inline-block`

Note: a good practice is to use class instead of id to identify the styling, and id more for future interaction when using script and interactions.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, you didn't answer the question, but you gave me an idea to not use flexbox in that situation, I don't know that inline-block a while ago but I do my research after you comment. I've found out what I have to do. Thank you very much...